# Dynamically create subdomains on AWS EC2 with Node js

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, wildcard-subdomain

How do I dynamically create subdomains for my Node Js app hosted on AWS EC2?

For instance, I want to allow users to create their own subdomains when they register such as john.mydomain.com.

Hosting: AWS EC2
Server: Node 
Front-end: Angular

Answer (score 1):

You would need to wildcard your subdomains so that everything resolves to `mydomain.com`. There's a node.js package for handling this. https://github.com/patmood/wildcard-subdomains.

Ref - [use dynamic subdomains with nodejs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40174490/use-dynamic-subdomains-with-nodejs)

Comment: thanks for your answer. do I need to make changes on Apache / virtual host as well?

Comment: Yes, I can't help you with Apache tho. I'm working on nginx. But one thing is for sure that you'll need to make changes at both places.

Answer (score 0):

you can use SDK call form nodejs to aws route53 with name.example.com with respective link to relative to path to web page

Comment: could you explain it in a bit more detail please?